# Prevent Spool to add SQL query in output file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

I want my script to stop printing the SQL query in the output file.

I have tried different method, but its just not happening.

```
sqlplus user/password@(TNS Entry) << EOF
SET head OFF;
SET feed OFF;
SET trimspool ON;
SET linesize 32767;
SET pagesize 32767;
SET echo OFF;
SET termout OFF;
SET verify OFF;
SET NEWPAGE NONE;
SET verify off;
@test.txt
spool file_name.csv
select * from Customer;
spool off

EXIT;
EOF
```

Could you help please , I want csv file to have just the result of the SQL query and nothing else.

Comment: What is the content of test.txt? Maybe that contains commands to turn some setting back on?

Comment: test.txt is empty. This file is suppose to capture sql query as output generated by spool.

Comment: That won't work. What you a doing is running the contents of @test.txt in sqlplus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your commands in a file. Then run that from SQLPUS.

So for instance make a file query.sql.

SQL>@query.sql

Now SQL won't put the query in the spoolfile.

This way SQLPLUS will listen to your set .. off commands. See the documentation.

*SET ECHO {ON | OFF}
*Controls whether or not to echo commands in a script that is executed
with @, @@ or START. ON displays the commands on screen. OFF
suppresses the display. ECHO does not affect the display of commands
you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus from the operating
system.**